# Do browser's consolidate nested functions?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, browser

If I have something like

```
function f1 ( )
{
    console.log("Jon Skeet rules.");
}

function f2 ( )
{
     f1();
}

function f3 ( )
{
     f2();
}
```

then does

```
f3();
```

directly invoke `console.log("Jon Skeet rules.")`??? I'm wondering because I'm using a Javascript library but I'm using so little of it that maybe it's slowing me down and I should just write from scratch in plain Javascript the few functions I need.

Comment: They might or they might not. Depends on the browser and what optimizations are supported.

Comment: It's not in any specification that that kind of optimization would be done so it's really up to any given version of any given JS engine whether it might try to notice that there is nothing else in your function body besides one other function call.  Personally, I'd be surprised if they bothered with this because it doesn't happen a lot in real world JS code.  Most people don't that simple with extra nesting.

Comment: Is using the library slowing down your development process, or do you really think the many small library functions do slow down your script execution?